# Clicking on left side of line number, the red dot is not appearing

Tags: visual-studio-code

RED dot is not coming by clicking on the side of line number.

It was working correctly before, but not workign noow.

Clicking on the left side of Line Number on VS-Code.

There used to appear a red dot, which is very helping during debugging and all. But it is not coming now anymore.

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Do you remember what version it was working in? 2) What language modes is this happening for? 3) What language support / debugger support extensions do you have installed?